# Azure SQL Database 100% DTU while query DTU usage is low

Tags: azure-sql-database

while running a load test the DTU of Azure SQL Database goes to 100%. The next step would be to have a look which query is causing this but the queries have low DTU usage. This can be seen in the picture below.

How to find out what is causing the high DTU usage?

[image]

I did run the query as suggested by Alberto, below the result. CPU is clearly the bottleneck.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following query tells you which resource consumption is creating DTU spike:

```
SELECT 
    (COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_cpu_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'CPU Fit Percent'
    ,(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_log_write_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Log Write Fit Percent'
    ,(COUNT(end_time) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_data_io_percent > 80 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(end_time) AS 'Physical Data Read Fit Percent'
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
```

Comment: Hi Alberto, thank you for helping. But this query will tell me if I have problems. If rows return >80 then this high usage, the sum is taken of all high usages and this is divided through the total number of rows, so it give a percentage of how my database configuration fits my requirements. If the load is high it will tell me that it doesn't fit will but it doesn't tell me why.

Comment: Share with us the results to provide you more queries based on your findings. You are welcome.

Comment: I added the results in my question. CPU fit percent is 0, the others are 100. So it's clearly CPU but all my queries have low CPU usage.

Comment: No. It is not CPU. It seems your current workload is I/O intensive. You can verify that using Query Store http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0010.htm

Comment: I used Query Store. I used individual queries but the results are the same as Application Insights. Application Insights is also using Query Store, right? Applications insights shows 100% CPU and the queries show only a few percent.

Comment: Let me know if you have many missing indexes  https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/06/29/identify-missing-indexes-in-your-windows-azure-sql-database/

Comment: No, when I run the query I get no results, so no indexes are missing. Also, I would investigate indexes when a query would have high cpu usage. But the queries don't have a high cpu usage. I want to know who or what does use the cpu.